# Migrating to Spring Graphql from GraphQL java kickstart

Tags: spring-boot, migration, graphql-java

I am working on migrating our service to Spring Graphql from graphql-java-kickstart. However, given our service is huge, it is almost impossible to just migrate fully in one go. Is there a way for both dependencies to exist at the same time, while we migrate each resolver step by step?

Just a PoC of adding the new dependency and creating one Controller, caused problems with the GraphQl context and the kickstart Context.